# Let's squash those unanswered questions!

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

As of right now, there are 35 unanswered questions on this site. Let's see if we can answer them all. I think this will help people to find answers to their questions, and keep on returning here. Let's see what we can do!

Answer (score 1):

excellent! I am in.

*does this answer, qualify for an answer of this question ?*

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of low-rep user access to the comment feature, it's impossible to both follow the rules for posting answers and request clarification or additional details needed to answer a question. My own request-as-answer to a question was just deleted a few minutes after I posted it with no explanation, despite a moderator's edit to the question after it was posted 16 hours prior. It remained unanswered and I attempted to help.

It's overeager moderator actions like this that actively prevent a StackExchange community from growing and taking off (ie, "succeeding"). I'm no newbie to SE sites; I've 49k rep on StackOverflow. Yet my treatment by the mods on this SE site have been ... heavy handed to the point of exclusionary rudeness.

All that to say this: Maybe more questions would be answered if the moderators would lighten up and give answerers a chance to clean up a less-than-desirable answer while their reps are too low to play the game the preferred way (since that way is often made impossible, preventing the user from growing in the first place).

This is a real problem that is actively discouraging at least one well-accomplished SE user from bothering to participate. Is this really what we want? Why so hostile?

Comment: Okay, so let me offer my apologies as the basis of my post isn't the problem. Apparently it was a web browser thing that isn't happening on my desktop. That said, my assertion about heavy-handed moderation stands. To encourage growth in the beginning we need to be more flexible to start with. So it can be abused at first... Irrelevant if nobody uses the community to begin with due to its over-restricted rulemongering. Besides, like it or not, cleaning up the abuses is what mods signed on for.

Comment: I'll add (because of lack of room) that I *want* to see this community succeed. I was part of the beta / area 51 participation and spread the word in my local ham community about it. It's not sour grapes, I promise - just a pattern I see in SE communities that too often never really take off.